# Understanding timesteps in scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am trying to solve a PDE using odeint and the method of lines.  My code is definitely wrong - and I'm trying to figure out where it is going wrong.

I am calling the ode solver using `odeint(odefunc,y0,tspan)` where `tspan = np.linspace(0.0, 0.5, 5)` & `y0 = 1.0*np.ones(3)`.

I tried printing `t` within `odefunc` and am confused by the output.  Despite the fact that I am solving up to `t=0.5`, the last t-value to print is `0.015081203121127767`.  The number of outputs matches tspan, but I cannot see how it could possibly be solving up to t = 0.5 when the last time in the de function is 0.015.  What am I missing?

My DE is time dependent - so this is making it very hard to figure out where things are going wrong because I don't seem to be *seeing* the times where everything fails.

ETA - this is failing, but running this without some of the irrelevant stuff I am getting the warning `ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.`, which I'm assuming is part of the issue - but it doesn't appear to be halting the code.

MWE

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import sys

plt.interactive(False) 

sigma = 2320
rho = 1000
gravity = 9.81  # [m/s^2]
g = gravity*3600*3600  # [m/hour^2]
S = 0.01
settlingVelocity = 0.02  # [m/s]
ws = settlingVelocity*3600  # [m/hour]
n = 0.04 # [SI]

J = 400  # [Ws/m]
k = 0.02
Cstar = 0.2 * sigma  # [kg/m^3]
W = 2  # [m]

D0 = 1.2 
Lw = 20   
L = 100  

tend = 0.5  # in hours
tspan = np.linspace(0.0, tend, 5)


def d(t):  # metres
    if t < 50:  # hours
        return 0.5
    else:
        return 0.05

def Q(t):
    return 3600 * (math.sqrt(S)/n)*((W*d(t))**(5/3))/((2*d(t) + W)**(2/3))

def h(t):
    return d(t)/2

def beta(t):
    return (sigma - rho) * g * h(t)/sigma

def Omega(t):
    return rho * g * S * Q(t)  # [W/m]

def PsiTime(t):
    return rho * g * Q(t) * (D0 - d(t))/(Lw)

N = 10
X = np.linspace(0, L, N)
delX = L/ (N-1)

def odefunc(y, t):

    def zetaEh(t):
        return k * (PsiTime(t) + Omega(t)) / (J + beta(t))

    def zetaEW(t): 
        return (2*d(t)/(W + 2*d(t))) * k * Omega(t)/(J + beta(t))

    def zetaR(t):  
        return (W/(W + 2*d(t))) * k*Omega(t)/(beta(t))

    def zetaEF(t,i):
        return (W/(W + 2*d(t))) * k * Omega(t) / (J + beta(t))

    C = y[:N]
    M = y[N:]

    print("time: ", t)

    dCdt = np.zeros(X.shape)
    dMdt = np.zeros(X.shape)

    dCdt[0] = (  # forward difference for dCdx
                -Q(t) / (W*d(t)) * (C[1] - C[0]) / delX
                  + (zetaEh(t) / (W * d(t))) * ((Cstar - C[0]) / Cstar)
                - (ws * C[0] * (beta(t))) / (d(t) * (J + beta(t)))
        )
    dMdt[0] = 0

     # gully channel
    for i in range (1, N-1):  # central difference
        if M[i] + W *C[i] * ws - zetaR(t) * (Cstar - C[i]) / Cstar < 0:
            reMass = M[i] + W * C[i] * ws

            dCdt[i] = (
                    -Q(t) / (W*d(t)) * (C[i+1] - C[i - 1]) / (2*delX)
                        + 1 / (W * d(t)) * ((zetaEW(t) + zetaEF(t,i)) * (Cstar - C[i]) / Cstar
                                            + reMass * (1 - (beta(t))/ (J + beta(t))))
                        - C[i] * ws/d(t)
             )
            dMdt[i] = -M[i]
        else:
            dCdt[i] = (
                    -Q(t) / (W*d(t)) * (C[i+1] - C[i - 1]) / (2*delX)
                      + 1 / (W * d(t)) * (zetaEW(t) + zetaR(t)) * (Cstar - C[i]) / Cstar
                      - C[i] * ws / d(t)
                       )
            dMdt[i] = W * C[i] * ws - zetaR(t) * (Cstar - C[i]) / Cstar

    # Final node - backward difference
    if M[N-1] + W * C[N-1] * ws - zetaR(t) * (Cstar - C[N-1]) / Cstar < 0: 
        reMass = M[N-1] + W * C[N-1] * ws
        dCdt[N-1] = (
                -Q(t) / (W * d(t)) * (C[N-1] - C[N-2]) / delX
                + 1 / (W * d(t)) * ((zetaEW(t) + zetaEF(t, i)) * (Cstar - C[N-1]) / Cstar
                                    + reMass * (1 - (beta(t)) / (J + beta(t))))
                - C[i] * ws / d(t)
        )
        dMdt[N-1] = -M[N-1]

    else:
        dCdt[N-1] = (
                -Q(t) / (W * d(t)) * (C[N-2] - C[N - 1]) / delX
                + 1 / (W * d(t)) * (zetaEW(t) + zetaR(t)) * (Cstar - C[N-1]) / Cstar
                - C[N-1] * ws / d(t)
        )
        dMdt[N-1] = W * C[N-1] * ws - zetaR(t) * (Cstar - C[N-1]) / Cstar
    dydt = np.ravel([dCdt, dMdt])
    return dydt


init_C = 0.0 * np.ones(X.shape)
init_M = 0.0 * np.ones(X.shape)
init= np.ravel([init_C, init_M])

sol = odeint(odefunc, init, tspan)

conc = sol[:, :N]
```

Comment: could you provide enough code so that the problem can be replicated by someone else? what is `odefunc`?

Comment: I'm trying to work on a minimal example that isn't 3 pages long - haven't yet figured out exactly what is causing this to not act as I expected yet.  Was hoping there was something obvious I was missing that would short-cut the process.

Comment: @DrBwts - I've provided an example that should replicate what I'm seeing (I tried to cut out the irrelevant stuff, so this one prints last t about 0.02).

Comment: The functions are a bit long to try to "guess" better. Can you try with more elements in tspan? `tspan = np.linspace(0.0, tend, 100)` for instance? `odeint` will divide the interval between `tspan[0]` and `tspan[1]` (same for next points of course) in smaller intervals over which the equation can be solved with sufficient accuracy. There is a fixed limit to this subdivision, hence my advice.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl - I think I might be understanding `tspan` in `odeint` wrong.  I thought `tspan` was the time points that a solution is reported, so the algorithm makes sure that it calculates at those time points, but unless it's really small doesn't influence the calculations. Is that wrong?  I've only a few here so the output is short.  I have tried with 100 and am still getting problems.  I keep getting nan in the output - but cannot track down why, as I never see near those timesteps.  And yep - ugly eqns but I couldn't figure out how to replicate the problem with something nice.

Comment: I'll play with timesteps some more and see if a unit transformation helps - the ROC is definitely not order 1 -  thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In principle what you write is true, but the integration method in `odeint` will only subdivide the interval in `mxstep` subintervals. You can pass the option `mxstep=1000000` for instance to check if it changes anything.

Comment: Printing out at a lot more timesteps seems to have solved the problem - I'm no longer getting it printing for less than the total time run.  I still don't understand what was happening - but problem has resolved.